# AVAudioPlayer - Sound Quality

Tags: xcode6, avaudioplayer, avplayer, avaudiosession

i made a djplayer for myself. everything works fine but the output-quality is very bad, if the rate of the avaudioplayer is not exactly 1.0 .

i already tried to change the sampleRate of my AVAudioSession. still the same.

the app is a skscene and i use the update method to set the avplayerrate on every frame, which i get from my jogwheel/turntable and/or from a fader.

this method works fine for me with the avaudioplayer except the quality.
so i tried to write the code for an avplayer, which gives me the quality i ned for this project but now when i touch the turntable or fader and change the rate, the sound completely disappears until the avplayer has processed the new rate.

can someone help me please?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: not until now sry